# Is there a way to use Any() in this LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Catalog>
    <Device>
        <Identity>
            <Key>
                <VendorID Name="Generic Vendor">123</VendorID>
                <ProductType Name="Something">26</ProductType>
                <ProductCode>78</ProductCode>
                <Revs>
                    <MajorRev Number="17" DefaultMinorRev="128" />
                    <MajorRev Number="18" DefaultMinorRev="128" />
                    <MajorRev Number="19" DefaultMinorRev="128" />
                </Revs>
            </Key>
        </Identity>
    </Device>
    <Device>
        <Identity>
            <Key>
                <VendorID Name="Generic Vendor">123</VendorID>
                <ProductType Name="Something">26</ProductType>
                <ProductCode>78</ProductCode>
                <Revs>
                    <MajorRev Number="17" DefaultMinorRev="129" />
                    <MajorRev Number="18" DefaultMinorRev="129" />
                    <MajorRev Number="19" DefaultMinorRev="129" />
                </Revs>
            </Key>
        </Identity>
    </Device>
</Catalog>
```

I read it using the following C# program:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace XMLSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xmlFile = new StreamReader("c:\\misc\\minimumxmlsample.xml");

            XElement catSvcsData = XElement.Load(xmlFile);

            // A device has only one vendor ID, product type, product code and revs element.
            var matchingDeviceKeys =
                from dev in catSvcsData.Elements("Device")
                where dev.Descendants("VendorID").First().Value == "123" && // device.Vendor.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) &&
                dev.Descendants("ProductType").First().Value == "26" && // device.ProductType.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) &&
                dev.Descendants("ProductCode").First().Value == "78" // device.ProductCode.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                from rev in dev.Descendants("Revs")
                where rev.Element("MajorRev").Attribute("Number").Value == "17" && // device.MajorRevision.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) &&
                rev.Element("MajorRev").Attribute("DefaultMinorRev").Value == "129" // device.MinorRevision.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                select dev; // dev.Element("Schema").Element("Capabilities").Element("DuplexSupported");

            //var matchingDeviceKeys =
            //    catSvcsData.Elements("RADevice").Where(dev => dev.Descendants("VendorID").First().Value == "65532" &&
            //                                                    dev.Descendants("ProductType").First().Value == "26" &&
            //                                                    dev.Descendants("ProductCode").First().Value == "78")
            //                                    .Any(dev => dev.Descendants("MajorRev").Attribute("Number").Value == "17" &&
            //                                                dev.Descendants("DefaultMinorRev") == "129");


            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

The program needs to find the device element for which one of the MajorRev elements has the given major revision number and default minor revision number.  The uncommented query works, but the two "from" clauses look strange to me, quite likely because I am much more used to using the Where() function and similar things than using this form of a LINQ query.  It seems to me that it should be possible to use Any() to see if any of the MajorRev elements match the target.  The commented-out query does not work because I need to use First() to specify which MajorRev element I'm getting the attribute from.  Is there a better way to write this query?

Comment: First convert your Linq query from keyword-syntax to extension-method syntax, otherwise it's a pain to read.

Answer (score 2):

A straight forward translation of your query syntax to lambda syntax converting the final `where` to `Any` yields:

```
var m2 = catSvcsData.Elements("Device")
            .Where(dev => dev.Descendants("VendorID").First().Value == "123" &&
                          dev.Descendants("ProductType").First().Value == "26" &&
                          dev.Descendants("ProductCode").First().Value == "78")
            .Where(dev => dev.Descendants("Revs")
                            .Any(rev => rev.Element("MajorRev").Attribute("Number").Value == "17" &&
                                        rev.Element("MajorRev").Attribute("DefaultMinorRev").Value == "129"));
```

Note this is not how C# translates to lambda form: C# uses `SelectMany` to pair `dev` with each `rev` and then filters the pair on `rev` and returns `dev`. This could potentially return a single `dev` more than once if more than one `rev` matches the `where` filter. My query only returns the `dev` once.

LINQPad is a very good tool for seeing how query syntax is translated to lambda syntax by the compiler. In this case, just add `.AsQueryable` to your first `from` source.

I think if I were writing this, I would be tempted to use `Element` instead of `Descendants` when you know the structure, and use `Select` (lambda translation for `let`) to minimize duplication:

```
var m2 = catSvcsData.Elements("Device")
            .Select(dev => new { dev, key = dev.Element("Identity").Element("Key") })
            .Where(dk => dk.key.Element("VendorID").Value == "123" &&
                         dk.key.Element("ProductType").Value == "26" &&
                         dk.key.Element("ProductCode").Value == "78")
            .Select(dk => dk.dev)
            .Where(dev => dev.Descendants("Revs")
                             .Select(rev => rev.Element("MajorRev"))
                             .Any(mrev => mrev.Attribute("Number").Value == "17" &&
                                          mrev.Attribute("DefaultMinorRev").Value == "129"));
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to answer in such detail!

I think Descendants would be preferable to Elements because it would make the code less vulnerable to changes.  I'm guaranteed that the vendor ID, product type and product code elements will always be present and unique and that there will always be at least one MajorRev element with the Number and DefaultMinorRev attributes, but I do not have a guarantee of where they will be in the structure.